# How do I set the 'X-Content-Type-Options' header in an Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-functions

Is it possible to set the 'X-Content-Type-Options' value in the default response headers of an Azure Function app to 'nosniff'?
I've worked with Azure Functions for about two years and know they don't follow the standard app.config/web.config paradigm, otherwise this would be an easy fix.

If it is possible, can this be achieved without having to install 3rd party plugins or extensions?

Thx,
Jemaal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, this can be done with [Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#modify-requests-responses), though in a slightly cumbersome way. Your proxy json should something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "globalProxy": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "methods": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ],
                "route": "{*everything}"
            },
            "responseOverrides": {
                "response.headers.X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will override, not set as a default, "nosniff" as the value for all requests. Also, if you want to use any other proxies, you might need to play around with the ordering, as I am not sure how proxy precedence works.

Comment: Thanks Connor. I'll definitely have to play around with the ordering and routes for my purpose, but at least it's possible!